Google Earth Engine Dividing Geometry Into 4 or 8 equal parts
I have a geometry in Google Earth Engine. It's basically extent of Landsat tile. For downloading an image in parts I want to break the geometry into parts. I have used covering grid, fishnet (geemap) but they are either generating chunk extents outside the geometry bounds or irregular kind of chunks that cover limited pixels.  I want patches to exactly match the extent of orignal polygon bounds. Here is what I am getting now.
Code Link: https://code.earthengine.google.com/2efced59d3d952a68a497c13612c7559
So far this is what I got

and I want something like this, a feature collection of 8 features over which I will map a function and download the patches

